# Vue cli3 chunk particular file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-4, vue-cli-3

I have a project that is built with vue-cli3 and i want to single out a particular file to chunk on its own for IIS reasons. Currently webpack chunks based on default settings. Chunks are also automatically created from my dynamic imports in vue-router.

How can i single out a specific file(config.js) that i want to chunk on its own?

file structure:

```
src
----components
----helpers
--------config.js
--------file2.js
--------file3.js
----views
----etc
```

So inside the helpers directory i want to chunk out the config.js file AND also not minify it. Its a small config file that i need to modify upon installing to a server so i need to alter it with installshield.

Is there something to configure in the vue.config.js file?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of vue.config.js add:

```
configureWebpack: {
  entry: {
    config: './path/config.js'
  }
}
```